# Android: Receive and forward text message from service

Tags: java, android, sms, android-broadcast

I am trying to make a simple app that will forward all messages with particular body to another number.

Broadcast receiver in my class is not being called. Any leads will be appreciated

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Settings.Applog("App started !!");
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SMSService.class);
    startService(intent);
}
```

SMSService.java

```
public class SMSService extends Service {

private IntentFilter mIntentFilter;
private SMSreceiver mSMSreceiver;

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate()
{
    super.onCreate();
    Settings.Applog("Service started !!");
    //SMS event receiver
    mSMSreceiver = new SMSreceiver();
    mIntentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    mIntentFilter.addAction("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
    registerReceiver(mSMSreceiver, mIntentFilter);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();

    // Unregister the SMS receiver
    unregisterReceiver(mSMSreceiver);
}

private String ConvertNumber(String from){
    return from;
}

public class SMSreceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{

    private final String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        String strMessage = "";
        Settings.Applog("Got a message!!");
        if ( bundle != null )
        {
            try{
                Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                SmsMessage[] msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                for(int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
                    msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
                    String msg_from = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                    String msgBody = msgs[i].getMessageBody();
                    Settings.Applog("Message body ::"+msgBody);
                }
            }catch(Exception e){
              //Log.d("Exception caught",e.getMessage());
            }

        }
    }
}
```

}

Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="mypackage">

 <application
     android:allowBackup="true"
     android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
     android:label="@string/app_name"
     android:supportsRtl="true"
     android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />

     <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
         <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
         </intent-filter>
     </activity>

     <service
         android:name=".SMSService"
         android:exported="false">
     </service>

 </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Permissions go outside of the `<application>` tags. Also, you don't need a constantly-running `Service` to get incoming SMS. Though you can dynamically register a Receiver like you are, it would be preferable to statically register the Receiver class as shown in Kowshick's answer, and start your `Service` to handle the processing and reply in the `onReceive()` method.

Answer (score 1):

You have to register the Broadcast Receiver for receiving SMS in the manifest file.
Just the permission will not work.

Inside the application tag it would look something like:

```
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true" >
    <receiver android:name=".SMSBroadcastReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"></action>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

</application>
```

Use this as an example for receiving the SMS message. It should be a good starting point.
http://javapapers.com/android/android-receive-sms-tutorial/

Comment: Well. I found alternate that really worked, But not the way i wanted.

I made separate file for Broadcast receiver (Not from service), it worked.